# Pointers to user profile frameworks in Java

Tags: java, frameworks, user-profile

I'm looking for pointers to something that I may be overlooking (or maybe something that Jivebot hasn't yet written for me). What I want is a pre-rolled Java framework for managing user accounts that takes care of most of the common tasks associated with such.

For instance, Jfacets is a good approach to automagic view controlling, but you still have to roll the view code. I wonder if there's a framework that has pre-rolled components for inputting/storing common user profile information, sessioning, and possibly things like inter-account communication, connecting to common social APIs, exposing an API, etc. (basically some/all of the common tasks that a user profile-based app would want). It can be quick and dirty, this is a prototype app at the moment.

I do know that user profiles are a very app-specific arena, and that I may just have to build something up, just thought I'd check first.

In the absence of a pre-rolled solution, I like what I see in Woko after an initial glance (http://woko.wiki.sourceforge.net/). The preconfigured stack includes Hibernate, Spring, Compass, JFacets, Stripes, and Maven and an API framework. I may just need to build the prototype up leveraging this as much as possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it looks like user profiles are just too situation specific for any framework. Shame, because there's a lot of basic functionality that could be served by a basic framework.

On the "solution" front, I'm attending the Open Source Bridge conference in Portland, Or. and recently saw topics on Scala (Two word description: Java scripting) and a framework built on that called Lift (three word description: CodeIgniter for Java). In short, these technologies rock my world.

Anyone looking for robust web frameworks should check out Lift. Scala allows people who love programming in Python and Ruby to use Java's JVM without the cost, with a lot of syntactic elegance (Scala is somewhat more intuitive to my Python-centric mind than Clojure). Lift is a MVC-style framework built on Scala which is just plain beautiful- and frighteningly easy to use.

Normal disclaimers, but the upshot is that it will take significantly less time to build an app-specific solution for a scalable Java app using these technologies than trying to find a user profile framework to use.